# Unable to locate element in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am getting the following error in Pycharm:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".fbc-imageselect-checkbox-9"}
```

It is producing this error on this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.fbc-imageselect-checkbox-9').click()
```

Where `driver` is the firefox, using selenium. I am attempting to click on the item that is linked to the CSS selector `fbc-imageselect-checkbox-9` on the website: http://topg.org/Minecraft/in-414300

Please note, changing your user agent to mobile will produce the grid of images.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this CSS selector work?

Comment: Hi, Could you please post the html code for the specific element.

Comment: You are trying to create a bot to get around reCAPTCHA so that you can robovote for something? Don't...

Answer (score 1):

Should it work? Probably not. When I view the page there is no such element (UA "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"):

```
jQuery.find(".fbc-imageselect-checkbox-9")
Array [  ]
```

You probably need to rewrite your query a little more robustly.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would target each individual checkbox in your view?

Comment: No. I don't know what check boxes you are talking about. In general CSS `input[type='checkbox']` would be what you would use, but it very heavily depends on how the page is written.

Comment: You can use either one of these when dealing with css `tagname[attribute='value']` or `.class=('value')`